# Looking for a reason the typescript class will not recognize properties in a class

Tags: typescript

Sorry, just learning typescript and running into issues following simple examples.
I have a simple typescript class as such

```
export class Todo{
    text: string;
    completed: boolean;
}
```

I get errors on text and completed.  however the video I am following step by step is not getting the same thing.  we have the exact same structure and objects.
[image]

Comment: [Images of code/errors don't help very much](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).  Please consider replacing the image with relevant information as text; particularly the specific errors you are seeing.  Ideally you should provide a [mcve].

Comment: I added the image to show the directory structure, file names and locations.  the code is above that and was reproducible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the following linting errors:

```
Property 'text' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
```

Which is correctly an error! I suspect later on in the tutorial you will actually set the values for these props. Something like this:

```js
export class Todo {
  text: string;
  completed: boolean;

  constructor(text: string) {
    this.text = text;
    this.completed = false;
  } 
}
```

Comment: While that may be true, in the video, he is not getting the same error at this point in time.the video is at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvWxMQ_Zios 1:30:00

Comment: Does he have typescript linting on?

Comment: His environment is somewhat irrelevant anyways, it's definitely a TS compile error. You can see here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4BUIBMJwDeAsAFBxwygwBccaMUAlgHYDmA3GRQhALZgkwKrjoAjCBCEoWcALxwAZiiRpgXUgF8gA

Comment: when he creates an instance of the class, it adds the import statement as it should, mine still shows it need work  v

Comment: I should have wated a few more minutes export class Todo{
    constructor (
        public text: string;
        public completed: boolean = false;
    ){}
}

Answer (score 0):

### Why does your code have errors?

If I had to guess, I'd say that you are using the [`--strictPropertyInitialization` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictPropertyInitialization) (or the [`--strict` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict) which includes it), and so the compiler is complaining that the `text` and `completed` properties of the `Todo` class do not seem to have been assigned:

```
class Todo {
    text: string;
    //~~ <-- Property 'text' has no initializer and 
    // is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

    completed: boolean;
    //~~~~~~~ <--Property 'completed' has no initializer and 
    // is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
}
```

That's an actual problem if you leave it like this and try to dereference the `undefined` properties while thinking they are `string` or `boolean`:

```
try {
    const todo = new Todo();
    console.log(todo.text.toUpperCase()); // compiles okay, but: 
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err); // ! todo.text is undefined
}
```

It is a good thing that the compiler has warned you about this.

---

### How can you fix the errors?

You can make the errors go away either by *initializing* the properties in question:

```
class Todo {
    text: string = "";
    completed: boolean = false;
}
```

Or by *setting them in the constructor*:

```
class Todo {
    text: string;
    completed: boolean;
    constructor(text: string, completed: boolean) {
        this.text = text;
        this.completed = completed;
    }
}
```

or some combination of both.  Or, you could decide that you will take responsibility for initializing the properties yourself and face the consequences if you fail to do so, by using the [`!` definite assignment assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions):

```
class Todo {
    text!: string; // no error now
    completed!: boolean; // no error now
}
```

This is only recommended in cases where it's actually hard to convince the compiler that the property is initialized.  Since one can easily initialize these particular properties, I really wouldn't do it in this case.

---

### Why does the tutorial *not* have the errors?

The tutorial is presumably not using the `--strictPropertyInitialization` compiler option.

Perhaps this is because it does not want very strict type checking.  While there may be valid reasons for this, I'd say that you should almost always use `--strict` if you can, since these options tend to catch more true errors than false ones.  For backwards compatibility reasons, the TypeScript compiler does not turn on `--strict` by default, so it could also be that the tutorial project just neglected to turn it on.  It helps if tutorials make it very clear which compiler options are being used, because changes in these options can have some striking effects on what compiler errors get generated.

Or it could be that the tutorial dates before [the option was introduced in TypeScript 2.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#strict-class-initialization).  This possibility is a rather important point (even if it's not the case for this particular tutorial): **TypeScript is being actively developed and is changing fairly rapidly**.  Any code that has not been updated in more than a few months is likely to show its age in one way or another.  Believe me, as someone who has a lot of TypeScript code in Stack Overflow answers, I am constantly being reminded that something I wrote three years ago is no longer accurate, and I either need to update it or point to a newer and more correct answer.   It helps if tutorials like this are actively maintained, or else make it very clear which version of TypeScript they support.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4FgAoJEpeAGxCiiQBUB7AE3ryNPaQBcIAPTgLiRROmYFgDcbDiQD0MgH7ykAHgC0qpAAU09GBDScAnkgDk3PiaQALKkmAsMwDJwwhyGAF76kIYIyRS0nJIGDT2nEiMEABmjs4Q5MZUUNjAEP6OXFbI8PTAwmgArvCc9GgAdESBHLlgMOQQ3IyCAEb09A2+ksTSSHKKA4oq6tq6+kamtfWN6ZY2YQ5OLm6e3r7+1ezBoXb0EVGxSwlJ1KnpIcBZOXkFxaUV1QC+VT0kIsYErzU3EaXMSABeOwQADudCY9AAFABKbq9Mg3DoQcrkehYSF-ejlcycbH0ACqMD0aAAwlQIDDYX0ZAi6hgGjR6ABrECGAA0SBahQEAS+jzIIE48CsSEh+jQ0NYX3YuXySJRaLFaAl4mpSEAvBuAUp2AIRcCHY3gRHaFPwxRzpJ5EZ6EIigSCwBDIACSSylMso1HB-0+8JxggKjhwQIARMG4b0pg0mq12p1LkDom4oBBwyRrdbbeBoHBEEgSfcAMqNN2kCjJL0sH29P1CESB1PfOpR9IxpFdTaln5FEplDGG-11sQcyMzZqc2MQXySqvwt5WUIGviAriGhu++dQcojprL7fpNeka3sdMvO3Zx1IACC1HGJZIZc9DG9Hbehu1A9EEhftOmTXf47bYAG3TIA)

Comment: there is no dispute that there is an error, I will look into this further to see if the tutorial handles it at a later time, I was just trying to do small pieces and test.

Comment: should have waited 10 more minutes into the tutorialexport class Todo{
    constructor (
        public text: string;
        public completed: boolean = false;
    ){}
}

Comment: I guess it just doesn't show compile errors in the IDE?  Or doesn't do incremental compilation?  ‍♂️